# Type 'MyError?' does not conform to protocol 'Error'

Tags: swift

I'm struggling to understand how the new type `Result` of Swift works. Here is what I have tried:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case test
}

typealias MyResult = Result<Data?, MyError?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Type 'MyError?' does not conform to protocol 'Error'

Why is this happening? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no need to make the types optional. Just `typealias MyResult = Result<Data, MyError>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The introduction of the `Result` type is discussed in [SE-235: Add Result to the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0235-add-result.md). One of the reasons was to provide a better solution compared to APIs like

```
func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

using both optional success values (`Data?`, `URLResponse?`) and optional errors (`Errors?`). The Swift language cannot express that *either* both `data` and `response` are non-nil *or* `error` is non-nil.

This leads to code which tests for “impossible” combinations, or uses forced-unwrapping (relying on the API *documentation*).

The `Result` type solves this problem by using an enumeration with associated values:

```
public enum Result<Success, Failure> where Failure : Error {
    /// A success, storing a `Success` value.
    case success(Success)
    /// A failure, storing a `Failure` value.
    case failure(Failure)
}
```

so that it unambiguously represents either success or failure. The `Success` type need not be an optional anymore, and the `Failure` type must be a non-optional error:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case test
}

typealias MyResult = Result<Data, MyError>
```

Example:

```
let resultOK = MyResult.success(Data())
let resultFailed = MyResult.failure(.test)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the `Result`'s signature:

```
public enum Result<Success, Failure> where Failure : Error
```

It doesn't accept an optional `Error`.

```
typealias MyResult = Result<Data?, MyError>
```

would work.

Comment: Most probably, the Success type should be non-optional as well.